# How display "today" instead of today's date in TWIG?

Tags: date, twig

I want to display "today" instead of the today's date, or "yesterday" instead of the previous day but I don't know do this in TWIG.

```
<p class="comment__date">{{ comment.createdAt|date('H:i d/m/Y') }}</p>
```

For the moment, I only get the date of publication of the comment.

An idea of ​​how can I do that ?
Thanks everybody

Answer (score 1):

You could add an extra filter to solve this, e.g.

```
$twig->addFilter(new \Twig\TwigFilter('formated_date', function($date, $format = 'd-m-Y') {
    $date = $date instanceof \DateTime ? $date : new \DateTime($date);
    foreach(['today', 'yesterday',] as $state) if ($date >= new \DateTime($state)) return $state;
    return $date->format($format);
});
```

Then use it inside twig, e.g.

```html
{{ 'NOW' | formated_date }} {# output : today #}
{{ '19-09-2019' | formated_date }} {# output : today #}
{{ '18-09-2019' | formated_date }} {# output : yesterday #}
{{ '17-09-2019' | formated_date }} {# output : 17-09-2019 #}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
{% set datediff = date().diff(date(comment.createdAt)).days %}

{% if datediff > 365 %}
    {{ (datediff/365)|round(0, 'floor') }} years ago
{% elseif datediff >= 30 %}
    {{ (datediff/30)|round(0, 'floor') }} months ago
{% elseif datediff >= 7 %}
    {{ (datediff/7)|round(0, 'floor') }} weeks ago
{% elseif datediff > 1 %}
    {{ (datediff) }} days ago
{% elseif datediff %}
    yesterday
{% else %}
    today
{% endif %}
```

`date()` will return todays date
`date().diff(...)` will return diiference beetwen todays date and date when comment created
`date().diff(...).days` will return difference in days

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```
{% set today = date() %}
{% set yesterday = date('-1days') %}

{% if comment.createdAt|date('d/m/Y') == today|date("d/m/Y") %}
   {% set print_date = 'today' %}
{% elseif comment.createdAt|date('d/m/Y') == yesterday|date("d/m/Y") %}
   {% set print_date = 'yesterday' %}
{% else %}
   {% set print_date = comment.createdAt|date('H:i d/m/Y') %}
{% endif %}

<p class="comment__date">{{ print_date }}</p>
```

Comment: Should use `>=` though